# Which sentence is correct? "Do you want to know what is it about?" or "Do you want to know what it is about?"

Tags: expressions

Which sentence is correct:
"Do you want to know what it is about?"
or
"Do you want to know what is it about?"

I am having a discussion with my partner. I think it's the first one, she thinks it's the second one because we ask "what is it about?". But in my opinion those are two different structures.

Answer (score 2):

The word order of a question (Who...? What...? When...? Where...? Why...? How...?) shows subject-verb inversion—

> Why are <sub>finite verb</sub> you <sub>subject</sub> sad?

But a clause with one of those interrogatory words at its head, when it is standing as the answer to a question, will show normal word order:

How **is it** done?  <sup>inverted order</sup>
-- She will show you {how **it is** done  <sup>normal order</sup>}.

Such a clause is  *a proxy for the answer*:

> Does she want to know {something}?
>   —Yes, she wants to know {what it is about}.
>
> What is it about?
>   —Bacteria in zero-gravity conditions is {what it is about}.

{Bacteria in zero-gravity conditions} = {what it is about}.

Only when you are asking the question or quoting the question verbatim do you use subject-verb inversion with these interrogatory words, because then you are asking the question or repeating the question exactly as it was asked, not paraphrasing it:

> Does she want to know {something}?
>   —Yes, I will repeat her question. She asked, "What is it about?"

Answer (score 0):

In an interrogative sentence when it's not embedded in another question we invert the verb and subject and in an embedded question we don't:

- What **is it** about? *(Interrogative sentence with subject and verb inversion; no embedding)*
- Do you want to know what **it is** about? *(Embedded question within an interrogative sentence without subject and verb inversion)*

The first sentence **"Do you want to know what it is about?"** is the correct one.

Comment: Actually, "what it is about" is still interrogative. It's an embedded interrogative clause.